# Can I use printer continuously in forEach loop?

Tags: ionic-framework

the plugin was auctifera-josed/starprnt.
ionic 3.
pseudo-code

```
products.forEach(function(product,key)){
 starprnt(product);
}
```

issues: print did not come out even loop finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
public printAllProduct(products)
{
      this.concurrentStart(products);
}
async concurrentStart(products) {
  for (const loop_product of products) {
     await new Promise( resolve=> setTimeout( resolve, 1000));
     this.printProduct(loop_product);
    }
  }
public function printProduct(product){ pseudoPrintFunction(product); }
```